# Dot Product of Vector Functions and Jacobian Matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f(x,y,z) = (xyz,x^2z^2,y^3x)$ and $g(x,y,z) = (x+y, yz, z-2x, x^2y)$.

I need to use the chain rule to find D(g $\circ$ f) which means I have to compute $\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial f_1}$ $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}$ but $f_1$ consists of $x+y$ and I am not sure how to compute $\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial f_1}$ when $f_1$ is not a single variable.

For the second part, I have to compute g $\cdot$ f and D(g $\cdot$ f) but f $\in \mathbb{R^3}$ and g $\in \mathbb{R^4}$ so the dot product is not even possible.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: When in doubt, go back to definitions: when you compute a partial derivative with respect to some variable, what happens with the others?

Comment: Define $f = (a, b, c)$ and $g(a, b, c) =...$ Then $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial f} = \left(\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial a}, \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial b}, \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial c}\right).$ In regards to the dot product, you are correct, it makes no sense.

Comment: It came out to be a typo with the symbols. What I was supposed to compute is the composite of g and f.. Anyways, thanks for the comments!